# How to filter out rows that follow a certain established threshold being reached in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
group <- rep(letters[seq(from = 1, to = 3)], each = 4)
date <- c("1999-01-01", "1999-01-02", "1999-10-01", "1999-10-05",
           "1988-02-01", "1997-12-25", "1997-12-26", "1998-01-01",
           "2000-05-01", "2000-07-01", "2000-12-01", "2000-12-02")
day <- c(1,2,274,278,
         1,3616,3617,3623,
         1, 62,215,216)
diff <- c(0, 1, 272, 4, 
          0, 3615, 1, 6, 
          0, 61, 153, 1)
matrix <- matrix(c(group, date, day, diff), ncol = 4, byrow = F)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix)
colnames(df) <- c("group", "date", "day", "diff")
df
```

In this case, "diff" is the difference between consecutive dates, in days, by group. I am trying to filter out all rows after an arbitrary threshold of "diff" has been reached. For example, let's say this threshold is a difference of 100 days. I would want to eliminate all rows on and after the first value of "diff" that is greater than 100, by group. In other words, my output would look as follows:

```
group2 <- c("a", "a", 
           "b", 
           "c", "c")
date2 <- c("1999-01-01", "1999-01-02",
          "1988-02-01   ",
          "2000-05-01", "2000-07-01")
day2 <- c(1, 2,
         1,
         1, 62)
diff2 <- c(0,1,
           0,
           0,61)

matrix2 <- matrix(c(group2, date2, day2, diff2), ncol = 4, byrow = F)
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix2)
colnames(df2) <- c("group", "date", "day", "diff")
df2
```

Is there some way to get this output? There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, but they do not accommodate groups, or do not work for my data. Filtering any value of "diff" less than 100 is not the solution, as it leaves me with dates that occurred AFTER the 100 day gap, which I do not want.

```
df %>%
  filter(diff < 100)
```

Again, I just want to find the first instance where `diff > 100` and remove this row and all subsequent rows for that group. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: A matrix can only have one data type. When you create a matrix with character, date, and numeric values they all get converted to character. Skip the problem by going straight to data frame, `df = data.frame(group, date, day, diff)`. This will also name the columns appropriately by default so you don't have to rename them.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks so much for the help. This was just toy data to illustrate my problem, but I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(group, date, day, diff)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(cumsum(diff > 100) == 0)
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
# # Groups:   group [3]
#   group date         day  diff
#   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a     1999-01-01     1     0
# 2 a     1999-01-02     2     1
# 3 b     1988-02-01     1     0
# 4 c     2000-05-01     1     0
# 5 c     2000-07-01    62    61
```